# Evaluating $\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\prod_{r=0}^n \binom{n}{r}\right)^\frac{1}{n(n+1)}$

Tags: calculus, combinatorics, limits, binomial-coefficients

> **Problem statement:**
> If
> $$ A = \lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\prod_{r=0}^n \binom{n}{r}\right)^\frac{1}{n(n+1)}, $$
> Find $A^2$.
>
> **Solution:**<sup>[1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TSsAP.png)</sup>
> \begin{align*}
> \prod_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k}
> &= \prod_{k=1}^{n} \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}
> = \frac{(n!)^{n+1}}{(1! \cdot 2!\cdots n!)^2} \\
> &= \prod_{k=1}^{n} (n+1-k)^{n+1-2k} \\
> &= \prod_{k=1}^{n} \left(\frac{n+1-k}{n+1}\right)^{n+1-2k},
> \end{align*}
> since $\sum_{k=1}^{n} (n+1-2k) = 0$. Taking log and limit, we get
> \begin{align*}
> & \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left( 1 - \frac{2k}{n+1} \right) \ln\left( 1 - \frac{k}{n+1} \right) \\
> &\to \int_{0}^{1} (1 - 2x)\log(1-x) \, \mathrm{d}x
> = \frac{1}{2}.
> \end{align*}
>
> **Source**: FITJEE AITS 2020 FT-8 Paper 1 of JEE Advanced question 53

Could anybody explain the solution?

I tried taking log both sides to bring the power down but got stuck on evaluating $$\sum_{r=0}^n \ln\binom{n}{r}$$ further I think the answer should be $e$ instead of $0.5$ which is given.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137643/discussion-on-question-by-aayush-srivastava-evaluating-lim-n-to-infty-left).

Answer (score 5):

We have the limit

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sum_{r=0}^{n} \log \binom{n}{r}}{n(n+1)} $$

Applying Stolz Cesaro, the limit is equivalent to

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sum_{r=0}^{n} \log \binom{n}{r}-\sum_{r=0}^{n+1} \log \binom{n+1}{r}}{n(n+1)-(n+1)(n+2)} $$

Since $\frac{\binom{n}{r}}{\binom{n+1}{r}}=1-\frac{r}{n+1}$, the limit simplifies to

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sum_{r=0}^{n} \log(1-\frac{r}{n+1})}{-2(n+1)} $$

This is now a standard Riemann sum, which upon simplifying yields $\boxed{\frac12}$

Comment: Well wow. I am amazed. I guess this was the best way.

Comment: @EthakkaappamwithChai thank you for the kind words!

Answer (score 4):

Let $A_n = \left(\prod_{r=0}^n \binom{n}{r}\right)^\frac{1}{n(n+1)}$ denote the expression before the limit is taken. Then

\begin{align*}
\log A_n
&= \frac{1}{n(n+1)} \log \left[\prod_{r=0}^n \binom{n}{r}\right] \tag{1} \\
&= \frac{1}{n(n+1)} \sum_{r=0}^{n} \log \binom{n}{r} \tag{2} \\
&= \frac{1}{n(n+1)} \sum_{r=0}^{n} \left[ \log n! - \log r! - \log(n-r)! \right] \tag{3} \\
&= \frac{1}{n(n+1)} \left[ (n+1) \log n! - 2 \sum_{r=1}^{n} \log r! \right] \tag{4} \\
&= \frac{1}{n(n+1)} \left[ (n+1) \left( \sum_{k=1}^{n} \log k \right) - 2 \sum_{r=1}^{n} \sum_{k=1}^{r} \log k \right] \tag{5} \\
&= \frac{1}{n(n+1)} \left[ (n+1) \left( \sum_{k=1}^{n} \log k \right) - 2 \sum_{k=1}^{n} \sum_{r=k}^{n} \log k \right] \tag{6}  \\
&= \frac{1}{n(n+1)} \left[ (n+1) \left( \sum_{k=1}^{n} \log k \right) - \sum_{k=1}^{n} 2(n+1-k) \log k \right] \tag{7} \\
&= \frac{1}{n(n+1)} \sum_{k=1}^{n} (2k-n-1) \log k \\
&= \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \left(\frac{2k}{n+1}-1\right) \log k \tag{8}
\end{align*}

Note:

- $\text{(1)}$ : $\log(a^b) = b \log a$ for $a, b > 0$.
- $\text{(2)}$ : $\log(ab) = \log a + \log b$.
- $\text{(3)}$ : $\binom{n}{r} = \frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}$
- $\text{(4)}$ : $\sum_{r=0}^{n} \log (n-r)! = \log n! + \log(n-1)! + \cdots + \log 1! + \log 0! = \sum_{r=0}^{n} \log r!$. (Or, substitute $r' = n - r$.)
- $\text{(5)}$ : $k! = 1 \cdot 2 \cdots (n-1) \cdot n $ and then use the property of $\log$.
- $\text{(6)}$ : Swapping the order of summation; the double sum runs over $(r, k)$ where $1 \leq k \leq r \leq n$. This is the same as $1 \leq k \leq n$ and $ k \leq r \leq n$.
- $\text{(7)}$ : The inner sum is $\sum_{r=k}^{n} \log k = (\log k) \sum_{r=k}^{n} 1 = (\log k)(n+1-r) $.

Now, $\text{(8)}$ almost looks like a Riemann sum, and it will be indeed a Riemann sum if $\log k$ were $\log \frac{k}{n+1}$ instead. So, it is natural to replace $\log k$ by $\log\frac{k}{n+1}$ and then examine how the difference behaves. Proceeding,

\begin{align*}
\log A_n
&= \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \left(\frac{2k}{n+1}-1\right) \left[ \log\left(\frac{k}{n+1}\right) + \log (n+1) \right] \\
&= \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \left(\frac{2k}{n+1}-1\right) \log\left(\frac{k}{n+1}\right) + \frac{\log (n+1)}{n(n+1)} \sum_{k=1}^{n} (2k - n - 1). \tag{9}
\end{align*}

However, we have

$$ \sum_{k=1}^{n} (2k - n - 1)
= n(n+1) - n(n+1)
= 0. $$

So the second sum in $\text{(9)}$ is zero and

\begin{align*}
\log A_n
&= \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \left(\frac{2k}{n+1}-1\right) \log\left(\frac{k}{n+1}\right) \\
&\to \int _{0}^{1} (2x - 1)\log x \, \mathrm{d}x \\
&= \left[ x - \frac{x^2}{2} + (x^2 - x) \log x \right]_{0}^{1} \\
&= \frac{1}{2}.
\end{align*}

Therefore $ \log A = \frac{1}{2} $ and hence $A^2 = e^{2\log A} = e$.

Comment: @ParesseuxNguyen, I guess you mean improper Riemann integral. Indeed, $(2x-1)\log x$ is not Riemann integrable on $[0, 1]$ so we have to be careful if one need to justify this step. (This convergence is not justified by the definition of Riemann integral itself. One may come up with some squeezing argument or something else.)

Comment: What do you say on applying the stirling approx for binom coefficient here? Would it streamline the proof or is it unusuable?

Comment: @SangchulLee wow thanks for the answer, i could never have thought the double sigma step thanks!